# Add image as a response in web demo (DialogFlow)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I just want to know if its possible to add images  as a response into chatbot web demo. If is not supported, how can I do this? How else can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge it is not at possible in web demo, you can add images hyperlinks or buttons in your website try exploring custom payload option, where on your website you will have to code by yourself, for the buttons when you send responses as custom payload and divert it to google assistant.

Comment: If this answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Web demo does not support images or buttons.
You can add some other chat client which supports images, like facebook messenger, slack etc.